# Half-Life 2D - How do I install it?

Tags: half-life-series

I have heard through the grapevines that there is a secret Half-Life 2D game that was released back before Half-Life 2 was officially available, that can still be installed onto Steam by entering  "steam://install/92" into your steam client.

However, I can't seem to make Steam accept this url - when I try to enter it as written, it just bounces me back to the cure and I can't figure out how to get this game in any other way.

How do I install Half-Life 2D?

Comment: According to @Elsvaer, it can't be installed on mac. (Copied from answer)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Codename Gordon, also known as Half-Life 2D:

> steam://install/92

Just paste this URL into your web browser, while you have steam running on your PC. This link does not appear to work in Chrome (tested on Firefox, Chrome, Safari and IE 11)

Comment: Aaah, so not directly into Steam itself. That's where I went wrong.  Thank you.

Comment: @Zibbobz The correct link ***does not*** feature `http://` since it's not an http link, but a steam one. Also, the link does not appear to work with Chrome; it works fine on Firefox and IE 11, however. I fixed the answer accordingly.

Comment: This also works in Safari.